# How define relative path to file?

Tags: java, path, cucumber, filepath

I have a project with cucumber and maven, work from Intellij IDEA.

I need to use a relative file path. Now I am working on mac os, but then the project will also be used on windows.

1. How do I determine the relative path from RunnerTest.java to application.properties file for mac os?
2. Will there be any differences in defining the same path for Windows?

Here is my RunnerTest.Java Class

```java
public class RunnerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.setProperty("TagConfigFile", "../../config/application.properties");

        //...

        String sConfigFile = System.getProperty("TagConfigFile", "null");

        try (InputStream streamFromResources = Props.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(sConfigFile)) {
            /* work wiht  streamFromResources */
        } catch (IOException | NullPointerException ee) {
            throw new PropsRuntimeException("Failed to access properties file", ee);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the image of my project structure (for clarity, added highlighting):

[image]

I tried to use such ways. But it did not help

```java
 1. "../../config/application.properties"
 2. "src/resources/config/application.properties"
 3. "../../resources/config/application.properties"
```

Comment: Your approach is wrong. You are not supposed to consider the properties as a "file", but as a "resource". As such, you are supposed to access it using `Class.getResourceAsStream` and then use that stream to build your `Properties` object. This is operating-system independent, and will work when you pack your project into a jar file (which your current approach will not). Please do some research on resources in Java. Here is Oracle's [Accessing Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) tutorial for starters.

Comment: If I understand the documentation correctly, then you just need to use `System.setProperty("TagConfigFile", "/config/application.properties"); ` But in this case, I get `streamFromResources = null`. Please help: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to remove the initial slash.

Comment: alas, it did not help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not pretend to be correct, but it worked:

1. I created the folder `resources` in `src -> main` and moved the folder `config` there. I created the folder `resources` in `src -> test` and moved the all other folders there. The result is such a structure:

```xml
src
 |----main
 |      |
 |      |----java
 |      |----resources
 |      |        |----config
 |      |        |       |----application.properties
 |
 |----test
 |      |----resources
 |      |        |----features
 |      |        |----pipes
 |      |        |----testdata
 |      |        |----webdrivers
```

2. Instead `System.setProperty("TagConfigFile", "../../config/application.properties");`
   I wrote `System.setProperty("TagConfigFile", "./config/application.properties");` in `RunnerTest.java` class

If someone offers a more beautiful working solution, I will be very glad